# What was the deal with 9:30 in M Night Shyamalan's 'The Visit'?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-visit

By the end of M Night Shyamalan's 'The Visit', it is evident

> that the fake Nana and Pop Pop were lunatics with a medical condition. Now, I read that some of the traits displayed in the movie by Nana are similar to actual conditions. Meaning some patients do behave like that.

But what was the deal with 9:30? Is it possible that a condition like this happens around a fixed time? Or is it simply employed by the director to create more suspense?

Comment: The movie never ascribed any special significance to 9:30 PM. It was merely their fixed bedtime and the time at which the WiFi was turned off. Nana would then wake up and do crazy things some time later at night, but not usually at exactly 9:30 PM.

Comment: Pop-Pop: Becca, T-Diamond Stylus, we're old people. Bedtime here is 9:30. See you in the morning. //
Boy: 9:30? //
Girl: 9:30. Oh. God. //
Boy: 9:30 (chuckling). This is gonna be fun. //
Girl: No Wi-Fi at 9:30.

Answer (score 2):

There is no other significance of the time other than that's when her delusion kicks in after the sun has set. The film is about sundowning, and it's title was even "Sundowning" initially. Shyamalan confirms this in the Q&A with Jeff Goldsmith podcast.

The condition of sundowning does not occur around a fixed time, but when the sun is setting or has set.

Comment: This doesn't really explain what the significance of 9:30 is in the movie, merely that sunset does not always happen at 9:30.

Comment: for the record, I didn't downvote you; downvotes are for bad answers. This isn't even *an* answer.